# Impossible to disable middle click paste

Tags: mouse

I am under the impression that the **Middle click paste** toggle under Mouse settings does not have any effect.

[image]

Middle click paste works with or without this setting enabled, which is kind of annoying. I'm using a Dell KM717 mouse (and keyboard). Am I missing something? How can I debug this feature and make it work?

Comment: I really need this to work and it is not working...

using linux for 10 years made me very used to middle click to paste, mainly stuff that I only selected. this gives me 2 clipboards.

so I can select some text and copy, then select a different text and paste both one with the middle click and the other with the ctrl v

Comment: Force of habit is strong. :) For me it messes with canvas dragging in graphics apps.